# Issues with component communicating with services in angular

Tags: angular

I created a service in an angular but when I tried to access a method of the service from within a component I get this error:

> ERROR in src/app/components/inventory/inventory.component.ts(90,34):
>   error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'DataService'.

Here is the inventory.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-inventory',
    templateUrl: './inventory.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./inventory.component.css']
})

export class InventoryComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.dataService.test())
    }
}
```

Here is the data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

    constructor() { }
    test(): string{
        return 'hello world';
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to fix this?

Comment: Is that all that is in inventory.component.ts? It says the error occurs at line 90, seems a bit further down that what you have shown us. Is there another line that refers to the test() function? As such it looks like you're called it as a property and not a function (i.e., console.log(dataService.test) )

Comment: please post your code on stackblitz, i couldn't reproduce your error
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dxjgh4. You could use augury plugin to trace if the injection is correctly done on your end